# is it possible to hide a vnode with mac_policy_ops in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, kernel

is it possible to hide a vnode with mac_policy_ops in Mac OS X? make a vnode invisible when using ls or Finder,by the way,chflags cannot  meet my requirements

Comment: As far as I am aware, the answer is no. All files can be enumerated by `ls -a` if the process has permission to open the directory for listing. If you describe what you are ultimately trying to achieve, we may be able to provide an alternative suggestion. Note that `mac_policy_ops` are a private KPI and Apple is actively telling developers not  to use it.

Comment: You can block lookups and listing via the `mpo_vnode_check_lookup` and `mpo_vnode_check_readdir` checks, but this will return runtime errors in the calling code, rather than "silently" hiding files.

Comment: thanks,i just try to hide a certain file with mac policy,but it seems impossible now